# Panasonic DP-1510P

Tags: drivers, printing, ndiswrapper

my issue regards ndiswrapper mainly. I'm trying to setup this printer

Panasonic DP-1510P

which is setup with an LPR queue on our work network. I went on the Panasonic website and I downloaded the Windows 32 bit driver.

When I run ndiswrapper the output is this

```
root@alessandro-TravelMate-8372:~/Desktop/dg2lviai090319# ndiswrapper-1.9 -i PFXSETUP.INF
installing pfxsetup ...
couldn't find install directive: "Panasonic DP-1510P"   = Pan15PIT.PFD
couldn't find install directive: "Panasonic DP-1810F"   = Pan18FIT.PFD
couldn't find install directive: "Panasonic DP-1810P"   = Pan18PIT.PFD
couldn't find install directive: "Panasonic DP-2010E"   = Pan201IT.PFD
root@alessandro-TravelMate-8372:~/Desktop/dg2lviai090319#
```

Do you have any ideas? I tried looking for this everywhere, but it seems no one has the "couldn't find install directive" issue. What could this mean? Should I modify the driver somehow?

Thank you for any and all help!

-ianhawke-

Comment: Anyone got a clue on this issue? I really need some help... Thank you!